# Matlab: variable-dependent dot product in anonymous function

Tags: matlab

I have an anonymous function like this one:

```
f = @(t) 5.*cos(t) + 10.*sin(t);
f([1,2])

ans =

   11.1162    7.0122
```

Is it possible to define *f* using a dot product operation or similar, something along the lines of this?

```
f = @(t) dot([5,10], [cos(t), sin(t)]);
```

(which obviously fails when *t* has more than 1 element)

My actual problem involves much larger vectors, where typing it all out doesn't look too neat.

Comment: Please use MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @JohnWO: The tutorial says much about typesetting formulas, nothing about code excerpts. What should I have done differently?

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing `dot` by hand:

```
sum((ones(size(t,1),1)*[5,10]) .*[cos(t),sin(t)],2);
```

I assumed t is an n x 1 vector.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for column vectors of the same size, $u \cdot v = u^Tv$. For row vectors we would have $u \cdot v = uv^T$.

Put simply, if your coefficient vector is a row vector, just write

```
C = [5 10];
f = @(t)C*[cos(t) sin(t)]';
```

Make sure `t` is of the appropriate dimensionality, of course.